# Abstract Algebra book where student must make most of the work?

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for a nice compact book in abstract algebra (especially group theory) which develops the material by asking questions the reader must answer. An example of what I'm looking for is Combinatorics through guided discovery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book *Groups: A Path to Geometry* by R.P. Burn fits your description.